# export_csv.py script missing from install?

Tags: ros, python, diagnostics, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ros-kinetic on ubuntu xenial.
I installed the diagnostics package with apt-get and I want to use the export_csv.py script, however when I run "rosrun diagnostic_analysis export_csv.py ", I get an error saying that the "export_csv.py" file is not found. I searched for the file manually and I cannot find it anywhere in the filesystem (I was able to find the exporter.py file which is the basis for the export_csv file)

Did anyone ever encounter this problem? (or similar with other python scripts)
Is there some setting that I have to enable to receive the python scripts from a package?

Thanks in advance for the help!
Kind regards, Roel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256873/export_csv.py-script-missing-from-install?/) by [Roel Helsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/29673/roel-helsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing the package from source. The error you are describing seems to [have been reported](https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/issues/51) some time ago, and it apparently still isn't fixed.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roel Helsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/29673/roel-helsen/) on 2017-03-14**:
Thanks for the quick answer.

I indeed installed it from source and that works, but I was wondering whether I had forgotten something or my installation had some problems. "Good" to hear that it is a general problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-25**:
This is fixed in version 1.9.0 of diagnostics. I've released 1.9.0 to the build farm, and it should be available in binary form in a few weeks.